# Chrome cannot find Chromecast with Toshiba Bluetooth stack

Tags: google-chrome, bluetooth, chromecast, toshiba-stack

Chrome cannot find my Chromecast on my Windows 7 (x64) machine. I've gone through the usual troubleshooting: they're both connected to the same wireless network:

[image: Illustration]

All the while, the Chromecast standalone utility **does** see the Chromecast:
[image]

I have the Toshiba Bluetooth Stack installed on my machine and I've paired it with my phone to get Internet tethering via Bluetooth.

Comment: More details would probably help troubleshooters.

Comment: I've added this "question" to document this incompatibility (in a Q&A format). What else do you want me to add?

Answer (score 1):

I've discovered that disabling the Toshiba Bluetooth Stack's "Bluetooth Personal Area Network" connection -- by going to Network Connections and clicking Disable -- allows Chrome to see the Chromecast again.

[image: Illustration]